# How to perform an action on button without using its ID in android studio?

Tags: android

I have not used any ID on button and simply mentioned the onClick proprty of button, in my MainActivity.java i mentioned the paramenter of onClick property i.e. "CLICK" but it doesnot work. Any solutions?
 `

```
public  void onclick(View v){
        Button button= (Button) v;
        number+= button.getText().toString();
        display.setText(number);
        rSet1= Double.parseDouble(number);

    }`
```

here is the layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.daman.calculator.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="349dp"
        android:layout_height="81dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:background="@color/Textview"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.514"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.037"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.027"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.402" />
    <Button

        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.305"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.402" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.583"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.402" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="4"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.027"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.595" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.305"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.595" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="6"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.583"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.595" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="7"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.027"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.787" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="8"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.305"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.787" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="9"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.583"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.787" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.305"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="."
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.027"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="operation"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.972"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.402" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="operation"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.972"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.595" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="operation"
        android:text="*"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.972"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.787" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="operation"
        android:text="/"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.972"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:onClick="calculate"
        android:text="="
        android:textColor="@color/DeleteButton"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.583"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98" />

    <Button
       android:onClick="delete"
        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:background="@color/DeleteButton"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.225"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.061" />
    <Button
        android:onClick="clear"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        android:background="@color/ClearButton"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.224"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.971" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: please show the layout xml

Comment: Edited the post. Please check and suggest me the alternative way

Comment: you wrote on the xml onClick then on code click... the xml string and the code should be smiliar.. both of them needs to have the same name.

Comment: solved the error but still not working

Comment: what is the minimum sdk in your project ? and in your device?

Comment: Project is running on SDK 15 and phone is running on Android 6.01! still not Working

Answer (score 0):

The onClick method should have the same name in XML and java ie:

```
public void onClick(View v){
        Button button= (Button) v;
        number+= button.getText().toString();
        display.setText(number); 
        rSet1= Double.parseDouble(number);

    }
```

Comment: isn't it has the same name?

Comment: No, you named it in XML onClick and in java click
either change the XML or the java.

Comment: you edit the post after my answer I didn't realize that.

Comment: i corrected that mistake but it is not working. i need to perform the same action from multiple buttons. i dont want to use ID's and create onClick Listeners for all the buttons. the code i wrote doesn't work, do you have any alternative?

Comment: its force stopping on my android device! i've read some articles and some of them say that onclick listener should work. but i dont want to create bunch of listeners. feeling helpless :(

Comment: As I said I have tried your code and it works fine please update your answer with the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: it worked! i forgot to initialize Strings. Thank you for your precious time

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
public void onClick(View v){
    Button button= (Button) v;
    display = findViewById(R.id.display);
    String number = display.getText().toString();
    number+= button.getText().toString();
    display.setText(number);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).